# Draw a diagonal line on specific boxes in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am trying to draw diagonal lines on specific boxes which belongs to class2.
I got this:
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdZAn.png)

My dataset:

---

```
samples genes   value   class
sample1 geneA   0.52    class2
sample1 geneB   1       class1
sample1 geneC   1       class1
sample2 geneD   1       class1
sample2 geneB   1       class1
sample2 geneH   0.4     class2
sample2 geneC   1       class1
sample3 geneE   0.44    class2
sample3 geneF   0.34    class2
sample3 geneB   1       class1
sample3 geneI   0.65    class2
sample3 geneC   1       class1
sample4 geneB   0.72    class2
sample4 geneC   0.41    class2
sample5 geneG   1       class1
sample5 geneB   1       class1
sample5 geneC   1       class1
```

---

Class1 is marked with yellow lines encircle the boxes. Can you please help me to figure out insert diagonal line on boxes belong to class2.

I want like this:

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajgp7.jpg)

Thanks,
kumarr

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kumarr. Please hover over the R tag - it asks for a reproducible example, with which one can  recreate your problem using copy,paste,run. See [this GIF](http://giphy.com/embed/3og0IEmawWtqcdLRug) and [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). You may want to use that in future postings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=genes,y=samples,fill=class)) + geom_tile()
p + geom_segment(
  aes(x=xmin,xend=xmax,y=ymin,yend=ymax), 
  subset(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]],fill=="#00BFC4"),
  inherit.aes=F
)
```

[image]

with

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.table(header=T, text="samples genes   value   class
sample1 geneA   0.52    class2
sample1 geneB   1       class1
sample1 geneC   1       class1
sample2 geneD   1       class1
sample2 geneB   1       class1
sample2 geneH   0.4     class2
sample2 geneC   1       class1
sample3 geneE   0.44    class2
sample3 geneF   0.34    class2
sample3 geneB   1       class1
sample3 geneI   0.65    class2
sample3 geneC   1       class1
sample4 geneB   0.72    class2
sample4 geneC   0.41    class2
sample5 geneG   1       class1
sample5 geneB   1       class1
sample5 geneC   1       class1")
```

Comment: Hi  lukeA, thanks for your quick answer. you are using "fill=class". But i want to use "fill=value" and in that case above code is not working. Can you please help me to figure out that. thanks!!

Comment: Maybe `p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=genes,y=samples,fill=value, group=class)) + geom_tile();
p + geom_segment(
  aes(x=xmin,xend=xmax,y=ymin,yend=ymax), 
  subset(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]],group==2),
  inherit.aes=F
)`. You should edit your question and follow to comment.

Comment: Many thanks, it's working now. But if you see my image1, i have put some gap between boxes by using my own code and when i am merging that with your code, it's showing error.

here is my code:

``ggplot()+geom_tile(data=data,aes(samples,genes,fill=value),width=0.9,height=0.9)+geom_tile(data=data1,aes(samples,genes),size=1,fill=NA,width=0.9,height=0.9,color="darkgoldenrod1") + scale_fill_gradient2(low="white", high="midnightblue", na.value="black", name="Cancer Cell Fraction") + coord_flip() + scale_x_discrete(name="") + scale_y_discrete(name="")``

Comment: `p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=genes,y=samples,fill=value, group=class)) +
  geom_tile(data=df,aes(samples,genes,fill=value),width=0.9,height=0.9)+
  geom_tile(data=df,aes(samples,genes),size=1,fill=NA,width=0.9,height=0.9,color="darkgoldenrod1") + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="white", high="midnightblue", na.value="black", name="Cancer Cell Fraction") + 
  coord_flip() + scale_x_discrete(name="") + scale_y_discrete(name="");
p + geom_segment( aes(x=xmin,xend=xmax,y=ymin,yend=ymax), subset(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]],group==2), inherit.aes=F )
`

Comment: Thanks lukeA, this is really awesome, thanks very much. 

I am afraid to one ask one more thing here. Actually, i also need boxes for combinations where no data is present (e.g. sample2-geneA; sample1-geneD etc) and i need to color these boxes as grey, just to discriminate from the others. Thanks very much!!

Comment: I know, i can do this by adding dummy data, but keen to know, if there is any other way to do this with this dataset.

Comment: Quick & dirty: plot those boxes on a full grid below the others. If you need help, post a new question as this has nothing to do with the original one.